# Drive with Final Cut Pro video files on it is dying, need to point FCP to the backup drive

Tags: hard-drive, storage, video-editing, macos, final-cut-pro

We have a 45 minute feature in Final Cut Pro. We've kept the video files on an external drive which is evidently dying -- like totally dying. Let's call this dying drive **OldDrive**. Fortunately we have a backup drive that has all the same files in exactly the same file structure -- it's an exact copy of the folders and files on the original drive. Let's call this **NewDrive.** **Unfortunately, NewDrive is a different drive with a different manufacturer and different name in the finder**. Since **OldDrive** is dying/dead, we cannot use any of the Final Cut Pro library functions to move the library from within. Is there any way in Final Cut Pro to just tell it to link all the video files on **NewDrive** instead? It would be a real chore to try and relink every file one by one.

Comment: If you're not using OldDrive anymore, just rename NewDrive to OldDrive in the Finder. The manufacturer is irrelevant.

Comment: @benwiggy so if the file contents of the two drives are the same and the names are the same, FCP can't tell the difference?

Comment: It may depend on which it thinks are in `myLib.fcpbundle` & which are external resources. [I'm not qualified well enough with FPC's structure  to truly distinguish]. It's definitely worth a 'try it & see'.

Answer (score 2):

Reconnecting the original and even proxy media is very easy in Final Cut Pro.

1. Disconnect your **oldDrive**
2. Connect your **newDrive**
3. Open the Final Cut Pro X library and open the media tab. All media which can't be found will look something like this:
   [image: Missing file]
4. In your top menu bar go to `file`, next `reconnect media` and then select `original` media.
5. Search for the files on the **newDrive**.

This [Apple support](https://support.apple.com/de-de/guide/final-cut-pro/ver26f5c8c9/mac) article covers this also very well.

Comment: @x-841 This is helpful information, and I have upvoted your answer. I had read that apple support article, and am aware that FCP will indicate broken media, and that one can reconnect media. What I'd like to know is whether it's possible to simply point every media link in the entire project to a new location without having to address each file individually.

Comment: @S.Imp usually when you point the first file it will find the other ones. In fact if the project (library) is in the root folder of the media it will normally find everything by itself when you load it. There is good change you dont have to do anything but copy the project to the newDrive.